# How do I figure out the longitude and latitude coordinates necessary to create a circular 1 mile radius around one location?

Tags: data, geometry, intersection, spherical-geometry, circle

How do I figure out the longitude and latitude coordinates necessary to create a circular 1 mile radius around one location? I don't mind how many coordinates that takes.

For instance: Latitude = 28.4789 Longitude = -81.4682

What mathematical **theorem** or **formulas** would you use to accomplish a task like this?

(I'm **not** using google maps, I just need to generate the necessary longitude and latitude to form the radius)

Comment: Once you realize that in (lat, lon) coordinates a spherical circle is (to a good approximation) a mathematical *ellipse* (except close to the poles), all the rest of the information you need can be found by looking at our [tag:spherical-geometry] threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) in conjunction with basic trig to iterate a series of vertices describing your circle.

Alternatively, if you have access to a GIS (e.g. ArcGIS, QGIS, PostGIS etc) or a GIS API (e.g. OGR, Shapely, GeoTools) you could simply buffer the point by one mile. E.g. for PostGIS you could use [ST_Distance_sphere](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Distance_Sphere.html) or ST_Distance_spheroid.

Also, one mile is not a huge distance so the error between spherical geometry and a planar approximation will not be great and may not be significant (depending on your use-case and accuracy requirements).  So, you could consider working in a projected coordinate system (choosing a suitable one centered close to your area of interest will minimise error) and dispense with Haversine.  Obviously over a greater distance it is more of an issue.  Only you can say how critical it will be.

Comment: (+1) But Haversine really isn't needed for circles this size until you are practically at one of the poles. It's enough to plot an ellipse of 2 mile major axis north-south and 2/cos(latitude) mile minor axis east-west where a "mile" is converted to degrees as if one were at the Equator.

Comment: Distance type to use for latitude/longitude is referred to as the orthodromic distance (also known as the great circle distance). As Mappa says though, since it's one mile only it probably won't make much difference.